# Comparing colour values

Tags: c#

I need to compare the Background colour of a Button with the colour of a Rectangle.

Based on what I found, I did this and it works. However, since I am not completely sure why, I am asking if this is the preferred way to compare. Especially since I don't understand why I have to cast them, if they are the same type anyway...

```
 if (((SolidColorBrush)button.Background).Color == ((SolidColorBrush)gameFill.Fill).Color)
    { ... }
```

Comment: You have to cast them because the `Brush` class (which is what `.Background` and `.Fill` will return) does not have a `Color` property. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.brush(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button.Background data type is "Brush" which means that the object could be
any one of

- SolidColorBrush
- LinearGradientBrush
- RadialGradientBrush
- ImageBrush
- Any other object derived from Brush

All of which can all be used to draw a background. However, the object 'Brush' does not have a property 'Color'.  The code example you have provided makes the potentially dangerous assumption that SolidColorBrush objects have been stored in both properties, which then allows the SolidColorBrush.Color property to be compared.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense now. If the assumption is dangerous (because it might break if the object does _not_ have a `Color` property?), what would be a more safe way to compare the two colours?

Comment: you can use *var scb = button.Background as SolidColorBrush* which will mean that scb will be null if the object is not a SolidColorBrush. You then need to consider the implications of either object not being a SolidColorBrush on the wider codebase (and why you are doing the check in the first place)